# how to set layout in landscape mode in android?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want my app support portrait and landscape mode, and I create a landscape mode based on portrait mode, but I can't modify the items in the landscape mode. How to make the description textview close to the picture?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create layout file with the same name as your existing file and override orientation qualifier:
[image] [image]

Then you can work with you `land` file.

Comment: I had already created a layout file with the same name as my existing file, and for override orientation qualifier, you mean modify android:orientation="vertical" ?

Comment: You can write different code in your portrait and landscape files. Just fix landscape layout and do what you want for landscape mode.